# iOS set image width in uitableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm not sure why my images are not identical in width in my tableview cells

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{    
if (self.mySearchController.active)
    {

cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(40, 60, 60, 24)
cell.imageView?.image = decodedimage
cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
return cell
}}
```

output:

[image]

How can I get all the images to have a fixed width before setting it to my cell

Comment: What's the contentMode of `cell.imageView`?

Comment: have you give any Constrains to image ?

Comment: I've tried cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill but havn't had any luck

Comment: If you are using auto layouts then you need to set fix width and height constraints.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell.imageView will resize your image to fit the cell height. if you want to have a fixed width, you could try this:

```
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:decodedimage.CGImage 
                            scale:fixedWidth / decodedimage.width
                      orientation:decodedimage.imageOrientation];
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Expected expression in container literal" in between imageWithCGImage:decodedimage.  I'm using swift 1.2

Comment: I tried converting it into swift -> UIImage.imageWithCGImage(decodedimage.CGImage, scale: fixedWidth / decodedimage.width, orientation: decodedimage.imageOrientation)      I'm getting unresolved identifier fixedWidth

Comment: @DevTonio which "fixedWidth" should be the value you expect.

Comment: Yes but then it complains about the / ..... Could not find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguements

Answer (score 0):

Three thing you need to do:

1. Set the frame size (and constraints if using autoLayout) that you want your image to be either with code or storyboard.
2. Set the `image.contentMode` to scale the image the way you want
3. Set the image's clips to bounds property to TRUE/YES either in code or storyboard.

This should ensure your UIImageView will be the size you want and contain the image within its bounds.

Comment: I've updated my code using your instructions above, but havn't had any luck

Comment: You should subclass the cell and only set the image in the table delegate

Comment: Will do thanks for the advice.  Any idea on how I can get the widths to scale properly?

Comment: Once you subclass the cell you should be able to change the width without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested it.you should add

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}.
```

Then you will find it worked.

Comment: I've tried using ScaleAspectFill and ScaleAspectFit inside of cellforRowAtIndexPath but it doesn't work

Comment: `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell.new()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "zzz"

        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"baby")
               // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    `

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `ImageView` yourself to your cell. that way you can have better control of it.

I'm not on a mac right now, so excuse syntax mistakes if any.

```
UIImageView cellImg = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
cellImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
cellImg.frame = CGRectMake(40, 60, 60, 24);
cellImg.image = decodedimage;
cellImg.clipsToBounds = true;

[cell.addSubview cellImg];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom class for your table view cell.
Do not use the name imageView to the UIImage object as it has some reserved properties.